# is there a way to get the id of the user who created/updated an active directory entry?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there a way to get the id of the user who created/updated an Active Directory entry? I can get the date the entry was created like this:

```
var directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
if (!directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property)) return null;
var createdDate = irectoryEntry.Properties["whenCreated"].Value.ToString();
```

However, I'm not sure what property name I can use to get the ID of the user who created the entry or if AD even exposes that property.

Comment: I think you'd have a hard time finding that information. The only option would be to go through event logs on the DC, if the user was created with the help of ADUC. Else, you're out of luck (possibly)!

Comment: Yep - that's the only way: event logs *on the DC that the operation was performed on* (only an issue if you have multiple DCs)

Comment: And Administrator Audit log if the user was created via Exchange (starting from 2010)